# Postback from Javascript call in Asp.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to disable a button on its click from javascript and invoking postback method from javascript, it works in all browsers except IE.

```
__doPostBack('<%=PayNowButton.ClientID %>', '');
```

When I checked browser and inspected button HTML code, it was rendered with additional code as follows.

```
onclick="return  disable();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$MainContent$PayNowButton", "", true, 
"111", "", false, false))"
```

When I tried to use **WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
    WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$MainContent$PayNowButton", "", true, 
    "111", "", false, false))"** instead of **__doPostBack('<%=PayNowButton.ClientID %>', '');** everything works fine in all browsers.

I have some doubts about it, I know most of the developers must have faced this situation and will surely provide their thoughts on this.

1. Is it good idea to use WebForm_PostBackOptions instead of __doPostBack?
2. What is the difference between both methods and what could be the possible reason for __doPostBack not working in IE browsers.?

Please help.

Thanks.